# Problem with scrartcl, fontenc and algorithm2e

Tags: koma-script, incompatibility, algorithm2e

I have a problem with scrarticle (and its option `parskip=half`), fontenc and algorithm2e:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[boxed]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \KwData{test}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

If you compile this document (with pdflatex), then there is no padding between the text and the frame of the algorithm. If you remove `parskip=half` or `\usepackage{fontenc}` (or both), then everything is fine.

What is happening here? Did I do anything wrong? How to fix this problem?

Comment: Unrelated: It's pretty pointless to load `fontenc` without option(s).

Comment: Of course, this is just for the MWE. In the real document, I use `T1`.

Comment: Interesting fact: it depends on the loading order. Loading `fontenc` after `algorithm2e` works too.

Comment: You can also replace `\usepackage{fontenc}` by `\selectfont` and you will observe the same...

Comment: The margin is calculated with \parindent, and algorithm2e obviously doesn't expect this to be zero when the package is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, I manually set the margin of the algorithm via
`\setlength{\algomargin}{1em}`.